# Custom sound stops when opening notification panel

Tags: flutter, notifications

I'm using flutter_local_notifications
Why my custom sound stops when opening notification panel?

I have used the additionaFlags property but it doesn't seem to work and the sound stops anyway.

I have used it as follow :
additionalFlags: Int32List.fromList([16]));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's upper that is the default behaviour to the android system
Which in the end does make sense